# How to correct response format for flask rest api?

Tags: flask, flask-restx

I'm developing a REST API with `flask` `flask-restx`. I want all my response will be formatted like this

```
{
"code": 200,
"status": "success",
"message": "OK",
"data": {
         
     }
}
```

```py
from flask import request
from flask_restx import Resource
from ..service.quiz_services import QuizService
from ..utils.dto import QuizDto

api = QuizDto.api


@api.route("/")
class QuizController(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.json
        return QuizService.create_quiz(data)
```

When do I make `GET` request on the following URL, it returns

```
{
    "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
}
```

which is expected as I don't have `get` method in the `QuizController` class, How can I customize this **Error Message**?

Comment: in the Flask file you have only `def post(self):` so if there is no GET function in `class QuizController(Resource):` it will return "The method is not allowed.
Try to add before the post function:
`
def get(self):
    return {
        "message": "OK",
}
`.
You can put whatever you want in the return dictionary - JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can catch for a specific exception on app-level

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def catch_error(err):
    return "hello", 400
```

If you want to catch only 404 exceptions you can use this:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound
@app.errorhandler(NotFound)
def catch_error(err):
    return "hello", 400
```